# Syntax error near 'WHERE emp_id = $emp_id' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to make a php form page for the users of my website. 
When I open the .php page I got the standard error message :

Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE emp_id = $emp_id' at line 1

Can anybody help me with the syntax of these commands ???

The Code is here :

```
<?php
include 'dbc.php';

$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$emp_name = $_POST['emp_name'];
$emp_address = $_POST['emp_address'];
$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];
$emp_date = $_POST['join_date'];

$sql = 'INSERT INTO employee SET emp_salary = $emp_salary WHERE emp_id = $emp_id';

mysql_select_db($dbname);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Replace `INSERT INTO` with `UPDATE`, `WHERE` clause is used for existing rows not for the new ones

Comment: You're trying to set emp_salary to a literal of `$emp_salary`..... use double quotes around strings for variable interpolation

Comment: Print out the string after variable substitution.  In about 95% of cases like this, the problem is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query syntax is wrong. You have to use `UPDATE` query. As you are enclosing the query in single quote, the PHP variables won't get replaced. So change

```
$sql = 'UPDATE employee SET emp_salary = $emp_salary WHERE emp_id = $emp_id';
```

to

```
$sql = "UPDATE employee SET emp_salary = $emp_salary WHERE emp_id = $emp_id";
```

or

```
$sql = 'UPDATE employee SET emp_salary = '.$emp_salary.' WHERE emp_id = '.$emp_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi again all you good people

I thanks very much for the amount of answers !

The right solution was found and the problem is solved with this statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `employee` SET `emp_salary` = '$emp_salary' WHERE emp_id = '$emp_id'";
```

Most of you was inded right about the syntax and the choice about UPDATE.

The above statement function very well, but it was  a bit hard to find the way.

Thanks again for all your kindness, help and time to answer my help

John Engelsby-Hansen

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql = 'UPDATE employee SET emp_salary=$emp_salary WHERE emp_id = '.$emp_id;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Insert query** should be

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO employee SET emp_salary = $emp_salary'; // it is valid without where clause
```

and there is no meaning for Where clause in Insert Qqery

Actually, if  You want to update record then write an **update query** where we have to set values for column

Like

```
$sql = 'Update  employee SET emp_salary= $emp_salary WHERE emp_id = $emp_id';
```

Comment: [check the 2nd comment at the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25485612/syntax-error-near-where-emp-id-emp-id-at-line-1/25485651?noredirect=1#comment39775890_25485612)

Answer (score -2):

Your Update Query is wrong

If its an UPDATE query then it should be

```
UPDATE employee SET emp_salary = $emp_salary WHERE emp_id = $emp_id
```

And if you are trying to `insert a row then how can you use a WHERE condition`?

`WHERE` condition are used in cases of `UPDATE QUERY, NOT INSERT QUery`

Comment: I changed the answer, and everybody realised their fault and change the INSERT query to UPDATE query.!!! LOL!!!

Comment: Your answer is still wrong as you don't tell him he needs to use double quote as with single quote the variables will not be processed.

Comment: It doesnt need to do anything with the single or double quote. Either use single or double matter is same... He is encapsualting the whole query string in a single quote, and assuming that emp_id is numeric, you dont need to do it like this '$emp_id'